# how to get xi in terms of n and sigma for a qqplot

Tags: statistics, exponential, iplots

I am stuck with when you set your cdf to equal (i−0.5)/n for when you are plotting QQ plots.

I have:
−exp−((x^2)/2σ^2))=(i−0.5)/n
Then I got stuck because I need to take the natural log of both sides however the −i−0.5n will be negative so surely can't have the natural log applied to it?

I carried on and got:

−((x^2)/(2σ^2))=−ln((i−0.5)/n))

((x^2)/(2σ^2))= ln((n/(i-0.5))

x^2= 2σ^2*ln((n/(i-0.5))

I really feel I have gone wrong.